# Comando para abrir o terminal em pasta determinada

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, osx, mac

Estou produzindo alguns scripts para preparar o ambiente de trabalho, e queria já deixar o terminal em uma pasta pré-definida. Como fazer isso?

Já tentei usando `cd ./pasta_selecionada` e `cd pasta_selecionada`, mas ambos voltam para a pasta original após o script ser executado.

Estou usando `OSX` e `zsh`, mas o script, até o momento, é compatível com `Bash` também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que seu script seja *arquivo.sh*, se você rodar

```
$ ./arquivo.sh
```

o conteúdo será executado numa nova shell, na qual existe, também, uma variável $PWD com o diretório corrente do script. Ao terminar, essa variável é extinta com a shell.

Já se você usar o comando *builtin* (na shell atual) `source` ou `.`, o conteúdo é executado na shell atual, permanecendo o diretório corrente do script na variável $PWD:

```
$ source ./arquivo.sh
```